# Comparación de días desde una base de datos

Tags: java

Quiero generar un ciclo donde se sume un día donde si es diferente de 6  y si el día esta activo la información la traigo de una base de datos, trae los resultados pero ya no entra al while.

```
           StrConsultas="SELECT fecha, dia, activo, fecha + "+ 1 +" AS fecha_final " 
                         +"FROM kalendario_entradaz "
                         + "WHERE (DATEPART(dd,fecha)= "+ fecha_inicio.substring(0, 2)+") "
                         + "AND (DATEPART(mm,fecha)= "+ fecha_inicio.substring(3, 5)+") "
                         + "AND (DATEPART(yyyy,fecha)= "+ fecha_inicio.substring(6, 10)+") ";
                 rs=MBD.SQLBD(StrConsultas);
                 System.out.println(StrConsultas);
                  while(rs.next())
                    {            
                    fecha=rs.getString(1);
                    dia=rs.getInt(2);
                    activo=rs.getInt(3);
                    fecha_termino=rs.getString(4);
                    }       

        while(contador<num_dias_afectar)
        {

                if(fecha_inicio.equals(fecha_termino))
                {
                   if(dia != 6)
                   {
                        if(activo == 1)
                        {
                         contador=contador+1;
                        System.out.println(contador);
                        }
                    }
                }   
        }
```

Comment: Esto se ve raro `num_dias_afectar=num_dias_afectar-1`. A cual `while` no entra??

Comment: Al segundo el primero si me trae los resultados.

Comment: Y en que momento `num_dias_afectar` toma otro valor que el de la inicialización??

Comment: Ya trae un valor solo a ese valor se le resta 1 para tomar como inicial la fecha que se ingreso

Comment: No no, con esto `int ... num_dias_afectar=num_dias_afectar-1` estás declarando una nueva variable, por lo que el valor que va a tomar será -1. Depura el código para que veas que cuando llega al `while` tiene dicho valor y por eso no entra porque no se cumple la condición.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿porque no utilizas consulas preparadas (*prepared statements*) en vez de concatenar la cadena?